# Remove part of URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite part of URL but without result so far...

My URL looks like this:

https://example.com/web/dashboard.php

and after rewrite should looks like that:

https://example.com/dashboard

Comment: Can you explain which technology stack along with code you are using?

Comment: I am simply using the core php.

Comment: Can you include code.